# regex look-behind expression incompatibily with IE

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I am using this regex expression for an input. When I try it in Chrome, it works well, but not when I try in IE. The regex editor that I am using advice me that the negative look-behind expression could not work for some browsers.

How can I adapt the expression to make it work for IE? I am using it to make impossible to end the input with /.

`(^(?!.*\/\/)^(?!^\/)[A-Za-z0-9\/\-?:().,'+\s]+(?<!\/))`

Negative look-behind expression not working in IE:

`(?<!\/))`

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a `/` at the end of the string, you could add another lookahead.

```
^(?!.*\/\/)^(?!^\/)(?!.*\/$)[A-Za-z0-9\/\-?:().,'+\s]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5m8hau/1)

But in that case, it might be easier to use a version where the `/` is not in the character class but optionally repeated preceding the character class.

This way, it can not occur at the start or at the end of the string, and there can also not be `//`

```
^[A-Za-z0-9?:().,'+\s-]+(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9?:().,'+\s-]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/whfD7Z/1)